# Problems with unbinding a function by handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox", checked="checked"/>
    <label for="checkbox">Copy values</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="source" type="text"/>
</div>
<div>    
    <input id="target" type="text"/>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to implement jQuery code to copy value from `source` input to `target` one, only when the checkbox is checked. Here's my code:

```
var checkbox = $("#checkbox");
var source = $("#source");
var target = $("#target");

var bindFunction = function () {
    var copyValue = function () {console.log("asd");
        target.val(source.val());
    }
    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        source.bind("keyup", copyValue);
    }
    else {
        source.unbind("keyup", copyValue);
    }    
}
checkbox.bind("change", bindFunction);
bindFunction();
```

However, it does not work as expected - for some reason the `copyValue` function doesn't get unbound. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5b93H/).

Comment: instead of binding and unbinding you can also use flag variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `copyValue` function outside of the `bindFunction` function.

This is because it was creating a new instance of `copyValue` each time the checkbox was clicked so the unbind was running against a different function than the one that was originally bound.

```
var copyValue = function () {
    console.log("asd");
    target.val(source.val());
}

var bindFunction = function () {        
    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        source.bind("keyup", copyValue);
    }
    else {
        source.unbind("keyup", copyValue);
    }    
}
checkbox.bind("change", bindFunction);
bindFunction();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5b93H/1/